# C# - Trying to create a threaded process using a function that has as Action as a parameter

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

This is a project I'm doing for my own amusement.

I started out wanting to experiment with combination and permutations.  In a console application I have the following code

```
    public static void Save(string newWord)
    {
        using (var db = new MyDataContext())
        {
            var w = new Word {word = newWord};
            db.Words.InsertOnSubmit(w);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var letters = new[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', '1', '2', '3'};

        for (var i = 2; i < 10; i++)
        {
            letters.GetPermutations(a => Save(string.Join(string.Empty, a.ToArray())), i, true);
        }
    }
```

In an extension class, I have the code to generate the combinations.  I found the code for the combinations here (http://blog.noldorin.com/2010/05/combinatorics-in-csharp/) for those wanting to review that.

```
    public static void GetCombinations<T>(this IList<T> list, Action<IList<T>> action, int? resultSize = null, bool withRepetition = false)
    {
        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        if (resultSize.HasValue && resultSize.Value <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(errorMessageValueLessThanZero, "resultSize");

        var result = new T[resultSize.HasValue ? resultSize.Value : list.Count];
        var indices = new int[result.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
            indices[i] = withRepetition ? -1 : indices.Length - i - 2;

        int curIndex = 0;

        while (curIndex != -1)
        {
            indices[curIndex]++;

            if (indices[curIndex] == (curIndex == 0 ? list.Count : indices[curIndex - 1] + (withRepetition ? 1 : 0)))
            {
                indices[curIndex] = withRepetition ? -1 : indices.Length - curIndex - 2;
                curIndex--;
            }
            else
            {
                result[curIndex] = list[indices[curIndex]];
                if (curIndex < indices.Length - 1)
                    curIndex++;
                else
                    action(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I thought it would be cool to calculate the combinations for all charaters in a list, each in its own thread.  So in my for/next loop, I tried

```
Thread t = new Thread(letters.GetPermutations(a => Save(string.Join(string.Empty, a.ToArray())), i, true));
```

But apparently, the Action that is being passed in, the call to the 'Save' function, is not liked in the Thread.  If someone could give me a nudge in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks, 
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Thread` constructor is looking for a delegate but you're appearing to pass a value instead.  Try wrapping it in an `ThreadStart` delegate.

```
ThreadStart del = () => letters.GetPermutations(a => Save(string.Join(string.Empty, a.ToArray())), i, true);
Thread t = new Thread(del);
t.Start();
```